# Hibernate NOWAIT does not work with SQLServer2008

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, hibernate

I'm using Hibernate 3.6.10FINAL and I am unable to generate a nowait command for SQLServer2008. I have tried using both dialects ("SQLServer2008Dialect" and "SQLServerDialect" (they both generate quite different SQL queries)) to no avail. I have tried the following:

```
List<TournamentTemplateRecord> leastRecentlyUsedTournaments = s.createCriteria(TournamentTemplateRecord.class)
            .addOrder(Order.asc("lastUse"))
            .setMaxResults(5)
            .setLockMode(LockMode.UPGRADE_NOWAIT)
            .setTimeout(0)
            .list();
```

```
List<TournamentTemplateRecord> leastRecentlyUsedTournaments = s.createQuery("from TournamentTemplateRecord ORDER BY lastUse")
    .setMaxResults(5)
    .setLockOptions(LockOptions.UPGRADE)
    .setTimeout(0)
    .list();
```

```
for(TournamentTemplateRecord t : leastRecentlyUsedTournaments){
        s.buildLockRequest(LockOptions.UPGRADE).setTimeOut(LockOptions.NO_WAIT).setLockMode(LockMode.UPGRADE_NOWAIT).lock(t);
    }
```

None of them generate a nowait query. This is the generate query in all cases:

```
WITH query AS (select
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
order by
    tournament0_.lastuse) as __hibernate_row_nr__,
    tournament0_.combattemplateid as id89_,
    tournament0_1_.combattypeid as combatty2_89_,
    tournament0_1_.combattargetid as combatta3_89_,
    tournament0_1_.resourcenameid as resource4_89_,
    tournament0_1_.resourcedescriptionid as resource5_89_,
    tournament0_1_.rewardloottemplateid as rewardlo6_89_,
    tournament0_1_.combatcontainertypeid as combatco7_89_,
    tournament0_.requirementtemplateid as requirem2_90_,
    tournament0_.assetid as assetid90_,
    tournament0_.durationinsec as duration4_90_,
    tournament0_.lastuse as lastuse90_ 
from
    tournament_tournamenttemplate tournament0_ 
inner join
    readyforcombat_combattemplate tournament0_1_ with (updlock, rowlock) 
        on tournament0_.combattemplateid=tournament0_1_.id ) SELECT
        * 
FROM
    query 
WHERE
    __hibernate_row_nr__ BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

How can I getmy queries to not wait for a lock?

**Edit:**
It's worth mentioning that `.setLockMode(LockMode.UPGRADE_NOWAIT)` and `.setLockMode(LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)` generate the same exact queries

**Update:**
I found out that this was an issue in the version of hibernate I was using. According to this [HHH-3961](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3961), this is not fixed in the version of Hibernate I am using (3.6.10Final). Upgrading too Hibernate 4.x is not really an option for me, is there a way to manually set the "nowait" hint for my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this question got a few upvotes and views, I thought I'd post my solution. I ended up doing a native query. It's not ideal, but it works well as a temporary workaround (i.e. hack).

```
TournamentTemplateRecord lastActiveTournament = (TournamentTemplateRecord) s.createSQLQuery(
    "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Tournament_TournamentTemplate tt " +
    "WITH (updlock, rowlock, nowait) " +
    "ORDER BY tt.lastUse desc"
)
    .addEntity(TournamentTemplateRecord.class)
    .uniqueResult();
```